# CORS for SignalR persistant connection

Tags: .net, cors, signalr

I am experiencing a trouble with allowing all origins for SignalR persistant connections. Seems, that caling "UseCors" has no effect. The endpoint initialization procedure (with CORS related setting) is as follows :

    `app.Map("/myendpoint", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll).RunSignalR<MyEndPoint>();
    });`

And attempts to establish connection from a js code on a remote machine still result in "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". Am I doing anything wrong, and are there ways to allow CROSS-ORIGIN requests?

Answer (score 0):

In Start up

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Werp.Wacc.Web.API.Startup))]

namespace YourApplication.API
{
public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    ///Configure Signal R
    /// </summary>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        app.MapSignalR();
    }


  }

}
```

Comment: You should *edit* your answer rather than posting a new one.

Comment: yes.I intended to do it ,now i have deleted my first answer.

Comment: I found out the reason of this nasty error, and it turned out something totally different : the app was running on linux (mono) under a user with very restricted permissions. Therefore request processing procedures would crash, return response 500 and skip adding CORS headers to response. In a nutshell : always keep in mind, that when you experience application error, you will also most probably get CORS error aswell, because application will simply skip adding any necessary headers.

Comment: did configuring signal R my way also skip cors